# Natural Language Processing and Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, hash

This question is about one of the applications of the Blockchain in **Artificial Intelligence**. I am not very familiar with **Natural Language Processing** and
I see that there is a Blockchain platform named "[Graphgrail](https://en.graphgrail.com/whitepaper/pdf/WP_eng.pdf)" to employ Blockchain for NLP and AI.

In its whitepaper is mentioned that:

> 7.1 **WHY DO WE NEED BLOCKCHAIN AND TOKENS:**
>
> Provision of the possibility of using data on a platform with mutual benefit for the **owner (?)** and
> **buyer (?)**. The Token allows the platform to hash in the blockchain
> platform the users and the results that they receive when training a
> neural network, downloading and / or spacing data. This allows other
> users, with the permission of the **owner**, to analyze the usefulness of
> the data or the trained models, use them and leave comments about the
> quality of the decisions applied. On the other hand, thanks to the
> protocol, users have the opportunity to monitor hashes to their
> blockchain at any time and receive an appropriate reward for their
> work, which they themselves will assign. This guarantees both parties
> the desired benefits.

It's not yet clear to me **HOW** exactly blockchain can help the user for an NLP operation?

What does mean : "*The Token allows the platform to **hash** in the blockchain platform the users and the results that they receive when training a neural network*" ? And what is the advantage of hashing the users and their results? (Is it for data integrity?)

And who is "**owner**" and who is "**buyer**"?

**And do you think in general is it logical to employ blockchain for NLP? and if so, is there an example?**

Comment: Honestly, that sounds largely meaningless and that someone just threw some buzzwords together in order to get people to give them money.

Comment: Thank you, Do you think in general is it logical to employ blockchain for NLP? and if so, is there an example? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like pure marketing nonsense to me.